# Segmentation fault when I fopen

Tags: c, file, file-io, segmentation-fault

I'm new to C file management . My teacher wanted as a homework to create a functon that copy from a source file to destination file . I created but it gives me errors all the time : Segmentation Fault .

```
void source_to_destination(FILE *source , FILE *destination)
{
    char name_source[10], name_destination[10],line[100];
    memset(line,0,sizeof(line));
    memset(name_source,0,sizeof(name_source));
    memset(name_destination,0,sizeof(name_destination));
    read_name_file(name_source);
    read_name_file(name_destination);

    source = fopen(name_source,"r");
    destination = fopen(name_destination,"w");

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),source) != NULL)
    {
        fputs(line,destination);
    }

}
```

Comment: **Always** check the result of functions which can encounter an error! Dereferencing a _null pointer_ is undefined behaviour. Note also you have to `fclose` the files **iff** successfully opened.

Comment: I closed them in main() . I think the problem is in `destination = fopen(name_destination,"w");`

Comment: The `source` and `destination` pointers are parameters of your function, but you do not use the argument values passed via those parameters.  That's not inherently wrong, but that and the fact that you do not *close* the files suggests that you think the caller will somehow receive the stream pointers from the function via those arguments.  It will not, and if the caller assumes it has done then that certainly could produce a segfault.

Comment: How can you close them in `main` if you cannot pass the `FILE` address to `main`? Maybe you should consult your teacher; there are some missconception. C is call-by-value only.

Comment: How would this copy a file cotaining an arbitrary number of zero bytes?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (` gdb` )

Comment: @Olaf That's not true. If you don't close a file you opened, `exit()` is going to close it for you anyway.

Comment: @FUZxxl: 1) This is bad design practise. 2) OP explicitly stated he closes them in `main`. So the question is what value does he pass to `fclose`? Very likely whatever in the (not shown) variables in `main` is -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. There see to be quite some places of undefined behaviour in your code.

Comment: @Olaf You're right ! It's wrong if you close a file in `main()` that is used in a function . This wasn't mentioned by my teacher . I think I will start a self-educate program .

Comment: @CălinCalin: It is not wrong to close a file elsewhere. This is very well common practise in larger programs. However, you do not pass the `FILE` descritpros to `main`. The arguments are **local** variables and not visible in `main`. However, in your code, if you do not need the file outside the function, you really should close it there (principle of locality). But that is not the only problem; see the comments.

Comment: I understood . Thanks again ! @Olaf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code

1. compiles cleanly
2. performs the desire operation (copy a file)
3. perform appropriate error checking
4. is getting the file names from the command line 
   You will need to modify this to get the file names via your existing functions
5. always cleans up after itself including closing open files
6. demonstrates how to pass the `FILE*` variables --into-- the function

   the sub function prototype, etc will need to be modified 
   if you want to open the files in the sub function
   then have `main()` close them.

Here is a suggested method of performing the desired operation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH (256)

// prototypes
void source_to_destination(FILE *source , FILE *destination);


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    if( 3 != argc )
    { // not correct number of command line parameters
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <sourceFili> <destinationFile>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of arguments

    FILE *fp_in = NULL;
    if( NULL == (fp_in = fopen( argv[1], "r") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen for input file: %s failed due to %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno) );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen input file successful

    FILE *fp_out = NULL;
    if( NULL == (fp_out = fopen( argv[2], "w") ) )
    { // then fopen failed
        fprintf( stderr, "fopen for output file: %s failed due to %s\n", argv[2], strerror(errno) );
        fclose( fp_in ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen output file successful

    source_to_destination( fp_in, fp_out );
    fclose( fp_in );
    fclose( fp_out );
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void source_to_destination(FILE *source , FILE *destination)
{
    char line[ MAX_LINE_LENGTH ];

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),source) )
    {
        if( EOF == fputs(line,destination) )
        { // then fputs failed
            fprintf( stderr,  "fputs to output file failed due to %s\n", strerror(errno) );
            fclose( source );
            fclose( destination );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
} // end function: source_to_destination
```

Comment: Failing to include the file name in the error message is a fairly serious omission.  Just do `perror( argv[1] )` and `perror( argv[2] )`.  Also, print all errors to stderr, including a message reporting incorrect usage.

Comment: thanks @WilliamPursell, I'll modify my answer accordingly

Comment: odd that some gave this answer a downvote, when I ran it on a number of text files, it worked correctly.  (however, I did not try copying binary files, as the question did not ask how to copy binary files.)

Answer (score 1):

When copying data from one file to another, reading and writing in binary is preferred. There are a number of reasons that reading with line-oriented input functions such as `fgets` or `getline` will fail to properly read all characters in a file. Text output functions suffer similar shortcomings (e.g. attempting to write characters outside the printable range or characters that have alternate meaning as ASCII)

Reading and writing from a file in binary mode using `fread` and `fwrite` is not any more difficult than using `fgets` and `fputs`. However, using  `fread` and `fwrite` you are guaranteed a correct and accurate copy of your data by avoiding the pitfalls inherent in attempting a general file copy in text mode.

If you know there is nothing but text contained in your source file, then there is nothing wrong with copying it in text mode. That just means you will have to write another function to handle files that are not text. (and generally you don't see different copy routines based on file contents). Reading and writing in binary eliminates all of these considerations.

The following is a short example of a `filecopy` function that will read all bytes in a file into a buffer and then write the contents of the buffer to your destination file. (a buffered read/write is generally much more efficient and you can easily adjust the buffer size by adjusting `MAXS`) The function returns the number of bytes copied on success, `-1` otherwise. Look it over and let me know if you have any questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXS 256

int filecopy (char *source, char *dest);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) { /* validate 2 arguments given */
        fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s file1 file2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int filesize = 0;

    if ((filesize = filecopy (argv[1], argv[2])) == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: filecopy failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("\n copied '%s' -> '%s' ('%d' bytes)\n\n", 
            argv[1], argv[2], filesize);

    return 0;
}

int filecopy (char *source, char *dest)
{
    char *buf = NULL;   /* buffer used to read MAXS bytes from file */
    size_t nbytes = 0;  /* number of bytes read from file */
    size_t idx = 0;     /* file index (length)            */
    FILE *fp = fopen (source, "r"); /* stream pointer     */

    if (!fp) {  /* open source for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", source);
        return -1;
    }

    /* allocate MAXS size read buf initially */
    if (!(buf = calloc (MAXS, sizeof *buf))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* while data read MAXS *buf from file - realloc for next read */
    while ((nbytes = fread (buf+idx, sizeof *buf, MAXS, fp))) 
    {
        idx += nbytes;              /* update total bytes read */
        if (nbytes < MAXS) break;   /* end-of-file reached */

        /* full read - realloc for next   */
        void *tmp;
        if (!(tmp = realloc (buf, (idx + nbytes) * sizeof *buf))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buf = tmp;
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close input stream   */

    if (!(fp = fopen (dest, "w+b"))) { /* open output stream */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", dest);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fwrite (buf, sizeof *buf, idx, fp);
    fclose (fp);    /* close output stream  */

    free (buf);
    return (int)idx;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/filecopy_simple filecopy_simple.c
```

**Input File (binary)**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 david david  66672 Nov 19 13:17 acarsout2.bin
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/filecopy_simple dat/acarsout2.bin dat/acarsout3.bin

 copied 'dat/acarsout2.bin' -> 'dat/acarsout3.bin' ('66672' bytes)
```

**Verification**

```
$ ls -al acarsout[23]*
-rw-r--r--  1 david david  66672 Nov 19 13:17 acarsout2.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 david david  66672 Dec 13 14:51 acarsout3.bin

$ diff dat/acarsout2.bin dat/acarsout3.bin
$
```

Comment: Good, but essentially a useless functionality to the many 'programmers' who only understand text scripts:)  They cannot cope with anything but text lines; their brains explode.  The answer that does not work was accepted instead:(

Comment: I concur. Matters not which answer was accepted, the important point is providing the reminder that not all files are text and providing a reasonable example of how to handle file copy in a general fashion. When you think about it, education is nothing more than a slow revealing of the truth -- all we can do is help pull the cover back a little further `:)`